# Correct way to typeset a section producing an underful box

Tags: typography, warnings

I am writing a two-column document and I have a problem with a section which produces an underfull box. What is the correct way (or some better ways) to typeset such a section so to have a beautiful output? This can be regarded as a general question as to what someone must do in such a case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Extension=.otf, UprightFont=*, BoldFont=*Bold, ItalicFont=*It, BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt, Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{ΑΝΤΙΣΤΡΟΦΟΣ ΜΕΤΑΣΧΗΜΑΤΙΣΜΟΣ Ζ}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I often see two-column docs with a ragged edge – that will likely get rid of the warning you're seeing (and the section title will look loads better)

Comment: @SeanAllred I see what you mean in the answer. It is pretty nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Sean mentioned in comment, it would look much nicer if set flushed to the left (ragged right). Here are two examples. One with `\raggedright` and one with `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` The second one allows hyphenation.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % load after fontspec
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Extension=.otf, UprightFont=*, BoldFont=*Bold, ItalicFont=*It, BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt, Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia}
\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
%{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection}{1em}{} % chose the one you like
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\RaggedRight}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{blindtext} % only for demo
\usepackage{microtype} % always recommended

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{greek}  
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
        \section{ΑΝΤΙΣΤΡΟΦΟΣ ΜΕΤΑΣΧΗΜΑΤΙΣΜΟΣ Ζ}
        \Blindtext
    \end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

**\raggedright**:

[image]

**\RaggedRight**:

[image]

---

As mentioned by egreg, you may use `\usepackage{sectsty}\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}` instead. This will be the shortest way, in case you do not want to change other properties of your section command.

Comment: With `sectsty` it's simpler: `\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}`. This assumes one doesn't want to change other aspects in the typesetting of section titles.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `scrextend` package, why not use `scrartcl` directly?

With the KOMA-Script features, this is a one liner `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\raggedright}`.

Here's a full example (I also removed the `parskip` package, since that's an option of the `scr` packages, too). Also note that the optional argument in `\setmainfont` is *after* the name of the font `\setmainfont{<font>}[<config>]`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{ΑΝΤΙΣΤΡΟΦΟΣ ΜΕΤΑΣΧΗΜΑΤΙΣΜΟΣ Ζ}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Even more, it's `\raggedright` by default.